# How to sort number when entering vector in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, vector

I want to add numbers in sorted way before entering vector. But the result is not right and I am confused where the problem is ? **Output is shown below.**

**I want to sort using some algorithm without any inbuilt methods.**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String ar[]){
    //Numbers to enter in vector
    int[] number = {5,2,98,3,10,1};

    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();

    v.add(number[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<number.length;i++){
            for(int j=v.size();j>0;j--){
                System.out.println("Entered: "+number[i]);
                if(number[i] <= v.get(j-1)){
                    v.add(j-1,number[i]);
                    break;
                }else{
                    v.add(j,number[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    for(int s:v)
        System.out.print(s + " ");
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Entered: 2

Entered: 98

Entered: 3

Entered: 10

Entered: 1

2 5 3 10 1 98

Comment: hint : your nested for loop is executed 1 time because if or else break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a second (inner) `for` loop based on the variable `j`, but that "loop" will only execute exactly one time.  **Both** conditions inside the `j` loop cause the loop to exit (`break;`).

When you're adding each number, the only possibilities are last or next to last.

Comment: I added that because, duplicate values are added to vector.

Comment: As you're looping on `j`, when you add the number -- yes -- you do want to `break;` (else you'll get duplicates).  But when `number[i] <= v.get(j-1)` is true, you don't want to add the number or exit the (inner) loop.  How much less than `v.get(j-1)` is `number[i]`?  Is it also less than `v.get(j-2)`?  Use `continue;` and find out.

Answer (score 0):

**Your inner for loop doesn't actually loop.**
Regardless of the condition `number[i] <= v.get(j-1)`,
the loop will exit after one step.

What you want to do is,
iterate from the beginning of the vector,
and when you find an element that's bigger than the one you want to insert,
then insert it, and break out of the loop.
This is opposite of what you did so far, which is iterating from the end of the vector.
If the end of the loop is reached without inserting anything,
then append the value.

The program badly needs some other improvements too:

- If you don't need the vector to be thread-safe, then you don't need `Vector`. Use `ArrayList` instead.
- The special treatment for the first number is unnecessary.
- The outer loop can be written in a more natural way using the for-each idiom.
- No need to loop to print the elements, the `toString` implementation of `Vector` is already easy to read.
- The variable names are very poor and can be easily improved.
- The indentation is inconsistent, making the code very hard to read.

With the problem fixed and the suggestions applied:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int current : numbers) {
  boolean inserted = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    if (current <= list.get(j)) {
      list.add(j, current);
      inserted = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!inserted) {
    list.add(current);
  }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Last but not least, instead of searching for the insertion point by iterating over the list,
you could achieve much better performance using binary search,
especially for larger sets of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop seems to not looping more than one time. That's why the key is not being inserted into right place.

A more concise solution would be

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String ar[]){
    //Numbers to enter in vector
    int[] number = {5,2,98,3,10,1};

    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
    v.setSize(number.length);
    v[0] = number[0];

    for(int i=1, vSize = 1; i < number.length; i++, vSize++){
          int j = 0, k = 0; 
          for(j = 0; j < vSize; j++) {
               if(v[j] < number[i]) {
                  break;
           }
           for(k = vSize; k > j; k--) {
               v[k] = v[k -1];
           }
           v[k] = number[i];
    }
    for(int s:v)
        System.out.print(s + " ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String ar[]){
    //Numbers to enter in vector
    int[] number = {5,2,98,3,10,1};

    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();

    v.add(number[0]);
    for(int i=1, j;i<number.length;i++){                      //j declared here for better scope
            for(j=v.size();j>0 && v.get(j-1)>number[i] ;j--); //<-- some changes here,
            v.add(j,number[i]);                               //<-- and here
            }
        }
    for(int s:v)
        System.out.print(s + " ");
  }
}
```

The inner `for` loop is simply used to find the right index for an element to be inserted.